# Using dropdown to display one datatable or the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatable

I have a wordpress site and I've had these two datatables working and displaying normally, but I've tried to incorporate a dropdown to use as a selection to either view one table or the other, but not both at the same time.

Below is the current code which is showing the first table and hiding the second (though it only hides the data, not the datatable search and page options for the second table). The issue is that the dropdown is not functioning at all. If I make a selection it just shows in the box but nothing changes on the page.

Again, All I'm looking to do is show #mytable on page load and have a dropdown containing #mytable and #mytableSurvey and whichever one I select should show.

```
<select name='tables' id='select-tables'>
<option value="mytable">Survey Test Table</option>
<option value="mytableSurvey">Survey Only</option>
</select>

//This is the code for the dropdown 

<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
  var table = $(this).val();
 $('#' + table).show();
 $('table').not('#' + table).hide();
}).change();
}(jQuery));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mytable').DataTable();
$('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();
$('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: I'm using the debugger in WP since I'm not on my local server, but none that I see. The page operates normally around it as well, so it's not crashing anything.

Comment: use `var table = $(this).val();` instead of `var table = $(this).find('option:selected');`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef did you get my update from your answer? I'm having a bit of a problem with the code and not quite getting the result out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
var table = $(this).val();
```

instead of

```
var table = $(this).find('option:selected');
```

so your code should be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mytable').DataTable();
   $('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();
   $('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');

   // select change event
   $(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
     var table = $(this).val();
     $('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
     $('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

**previous code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#mytable').DataTable();
       $('#mytableSurvey').DataTable();
       $('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');

       // select change event
       $('#select-tables').on('change', function(){
         var table = $(this).val();
         $('#' + table).show();
         $('table').not('#' + table).hide();
        }).change();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it still has  }(jQuery)); after the .change, right? That's how I ran it and it still does not load selection from box

Comment: @TomN. answer updated .. the above code should work fine

Comment: I updated my original question with the current code. I tried what you gave me here again, and it wouldn't build the datatables at all. Just plain html tables. Once I split the code with /script and <script> tags, the tables show back up again but no dropdown functionality.

Comment: @TomN. you may need `$(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){` instead of `$('#select-tables').on('change', function(){`

Comment: @TomN. and I can't find this code on your [website](http://www.testing.uwsinc.net/dashboardtest/)

Comment: @TomN. close the datatable.js </script>

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. ONly other questions: when it shows one table and hides the other it still shows the search and scroll bar for the hidden table. Is there a way to make it hide all elements of that table?

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you! So If I only want it to show one of the tables on page load would I just set it to show when the datatables are initialized?

Comment: @TomN. Actually `.change` shall do that for you .. but while it don't you can make it manually with `.hide()` and `.show()` as you were did before .. or you can copy/paste my code and try it again

Comment: @TomN. and please copy/paste my code as it is don't add or remove anything

Comment: @TomN. and instead of `hide()` and `show()` you can use css by add `#mytableSurvey_wrapper{ display : none; }`

Comment: The update before this one was working with the dropdown and now it's back to just showing both tables regardless. I copied this over exactly.

Comment: @TomN. I'm sure my code should work..but maybe the datatable take some time to take effect .. anyway keep coding with the working one .. good luck , and have a great day :-)

Comment: Sorry, your code actually did work but I believe it was the update right before this previous one you did. It was about 3 minutes before I believe. Do you have that code still, without the wrapper hiding? Apologies, I just lost it

Comment: @TomN. answer updated with previous code but you will need to use the one with wrapper to hide search bar

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thank you so much!